# Meteor mongo get this value

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a meteor game
[image]

On the server i have a timer that calls meteor method moveFish.

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
    Meteor.setInterval(function(){
        Meteor.call("moveFish")
    }, 40);
});
```

That method selects all fishes are alive and make them move

```
Meteor.methods({
    moveFish: function(id, speed) {
        Meteor.users.update( { "fish.alive": true }, { $inc: { "fish.positionX": 2 } } )
    }
})
```

[image]

How do I move fish using **`this.fish.speed`** instead value 2

```
Meteor.users.update( { "fish.alive": true }, { $inc: { "fish.positionX": 2 } } )
```

*Notice that doesn't work

```
Meteor.users.update( { "fish.alive": true }, { $inc: { "fish.positionX": "fish.speed" } } )
```

---

That's works

```
Meteor.users.find().map( function(user) { x = user.fish.speed Meteor.users.update(user, {$inc: {"fish.positionX": x} }) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately document can't use the reference to itself on update operation.

You need to find it first and iterate over all documents manually in this case:

```
Meteor.users.findAll({ "fish.alive": true }).fetch().forEach(function(fish) {
  fish.positionX += fish.speed;
  fish.save();
});
```

Comment: That's totally works
Meteor.users.find().map( function(user) {
            x = user.fish.speed
            Meteor.users.update(user, {$inc: {"fish.positionX": x} })            
        });

Comment: Yes, but working with the document itself looks much simpler than "update" function.

Comment: You're right. But i'm not confident about good performance. So i keep hoping